# GraphQLTestCase: AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'

Tags: python-unittest, setcookie, graphene-django

I would want to test my graphql mutation which should set a HTTP only cookie.

I use graphene-django GraphQTestCase

```
class CookieTest(GraphQLTestCase):
  def test_set_cookie(self):
    response = self.query(...) # This should return WSGIRequest
    cookie = response.COOKIES.get('myCookie') # This line throws an attrib error
    self.assertIsNotNone(cookie)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason response.cookies works, and returns `http.cookies.SimpleCookie` object:

So the correct way would be:

```
myCookie = response.cookies.get('myCookie')
myCookie.key # 'myCookie'
myCookie.value # <cookie-value>
```